Cython - How do we implement Tuple of Object in Cython?
I want to implement tuple of object in my cython project.
I couldn't find a way to implement in .pyx file so that I can use it in python.
You can check my get_language method for some reference.
And please help me with my get_value method which has tuple of object as parameter and returns tuple of object value.
In CPP Side
#include "Career.h"
#include "Language.h"

using triple_language_ptr = std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<_Language>, std::shared_ptr<_Language>, std::shared_ptr<_Language>>
    
class _Career{

    std::shared_ptr<_Language> get_language(std::shared_ptr<_Language> value);

    triple_language_ptr get_value(triple_language_ptr value);
}

In Cython Side
[career.pxd]
cdef extern from "Career.h":
    cdef cppclass _Line:

       _Career(...)

       shared_ptr[_Language] get_language(shared_ptr[_Language] value)

       tuple[shared_ptr[_Language], shared_ptr[_Language],shared_ptr[_Language]] get_value(
                 tuple[shared_ptr[_Language], shared_ptr[_Language], shared_ptr[_Language]] value
           )

cdef class Career:
    cdef shared_ptr[_Career] career_ptr

[career.pyx]
cdef class Career:

   def __cinit__(...):
        pass

   def get_language(self, value: Language):
        cdef Language py_lang = Language()
        py_lang.lang_ptr = self.career_ptr.get().get_language(value.lang_ptr)
        return py_lang

   def get_value(self, value: ???):
        # Fill this part of code for me
        pass


There's no need to type the input argument (value) - you should just let it be a Python object.
You can convert value to a C++ tuple with:
cdef triple_language_ptr as_cpp_tuple = triple_language_ptr(
    (<Language>value[0]).lang_ptr,
    (<Language>value[1]).lang_ptr,
    (<Language>value[2]).lang_ptr,
)

(this relies on you having declared the existence of a suitable constructor for triple_language_ptr). The cast to <Language> checks that it's a Cython Language object, and then lets you access cdef attributes of it.
To convert back, you need to wrap std::get. I'd do:
cdef extern from *:
    shared_ptr[_Language] get0 "get<0>" (triple_language_ptr)
    ...  # same for get1 and get2

Here the "get<0>" string just tells exactly what C++ code to generate, so when you type get0 in Cython, it generates get<0> in C++.
You then just use this to get the three shared_ptrs out of the C++ tuple, convert those to Python Language classes (as you do in your example) and return a Python tuple of those.
